# How to test a Fragment with static instantiation method which expects some objects as argument

Tags: android, mockito, android-espresso

I have a fragment which has a static instantiation method. It expects some arguments which are objects of some Custom classes . I want to write UTs for them and i am using launchFragmentInContainer for the same. Is there a way i can call this static method which initializes the fragment before fragment is shown ?

I know there is launchFragment method where we can pass bundle args and FragmentFactory . But i am using neither of them .

Fragment Code :

```
public class MyDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {
    static Person mPerson;

    static MyDialogFragment newInstance(Person person) {
        MyDialogFragment f = new MyDialogFragment();
        mPerson = person
        return f;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    }
}
```

Test:

```
@Test
    fun testMyDialogFragment() {
        with(launchFragment <MyDialogFragment>()) {
            onFragment {fragment ->
                assertNotNull(fragment.dialog)
            }
        }
    }
```

I expect launchFragmentContainer should have a way to call such static method before launching fragment